# How to reload a specific div on change of screen size using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I need to reload a specific div containing Images from data base at specific resolutions.
Issue is that when using tablet I change the view from landscape to potrait all the Images in the div appear scattered and after page reload they appear fine. So is there any way using jquery that I can reload the specific div lets say it as

```
 <div id="Images">
```

on the change of screen size.

Comment: Look into using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery function `$( window ).resize();`.
The event is triggered each time the window is resized.

Comment: I know that I have to use it `$(window).resize()` function
I am trying it this way 
`        $(window).resize(function () {
            $("#thumbnails").load();
        });`
Issue is on Ipad and I dont have an IPAD right now so i need a confirm solutions

Comment: Are you loading the images via an ajax function?

Comment: No I am calling them through xslt, actually I am using Umbraco,
and then there is a category jquery function, that filters the images

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. I tried the follwing code and it worked.
I added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

to the html header.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: this answer doesn't seem to be related to the question. your answer has nothing to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach to reload specific div

```
     $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() > 767 && $(window).width() < 1024) {
        setInterval(function () {
            $("#thumbnails").load('@Umbraco.RenderMacro("ctaPeople")')

        }, 500);
        //alert("load working");
    }
});
```